# Waiting for content loading in Appium

Tags: ruby, appium

I read manuals, but I'm confused yet, when it's necessary to use `wait` method in Appium. So, what I have to implement (on Ruby):

1. When app starts, it shows Sign in activity. I enter log in data there and click Sign in button.
2. App goes to another activity. First, empty screen is shown with circular progressbar, then loaded data is shown.
3. I want to tap on this screen in specified place.

My code is:

```
textfield(1).send_key('login')
textfield(2).send_key('password')
button(1).click
Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 0.5, y: 0.5).perform
```

In arc it works perfectly, but when it's running in tests I have a problem on step two: it seems tap is executed on empty screen, when data is not loaded yet. So, how can I tell to test that it's necessary to wait some time?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ruby,
 In python we use this after line of code to wait for specified time you can   give 5,10,15,20 in seconds as required.

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: in ruby
    "browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10"

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'browser'`. But `driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10` executes without errors. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: one more way is that you import time

       import time
       from time import sleep
  then use  
       sleep(5)